# what is the meaning of bucketing water?

Tags: expression-choice

> It's been bucketing water the whole day.

What does this sentence mean? Is it formal use of language?

Comment: The only way I'd understand "bucketing" would be in the same sense as "bailing" -- to move water with the repeated use of a bucket.

Comment: I've only heard the variant: "It's [been] bucketing" meaning it's raining hard.

Answer (score 3):

It's informal, and it means it is raining so hard, it's as though someone were pouring buckets of water down around you.

> (intransitive) often followed by *down* (of rain) **to fall very heavily**   ⇒
>   "it bucketed all day"

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bucket

Comment: Do the native speaker of English use it regularly in their everyday language? What are the specific contexts to use it?

Comment: @subas: I don't know about 'regularly', but then I live in a climate where the sort of rain that I'd describe as "bucketing down" occurs only rarely.  It is used, though: I've heard it, seen it in writing, and have used it myself when circumstances warrant.  Though usually you'd say "bucketing down" when speaking of rain, so the water would be implicit.

Comment: My personal experience in the U.S. is that it is somewhat more common to say "It's raining cats and dogs."  You can also say "It's coming down in sheets."  If I were going to use the word "bucket" I would say "It's coming down in buckets."  But I wouldn't have any trouble understanding your sentence.

Comment: We use it at at times when it is raining hard. It is entirely polite but we use it in informal situations and not in formal conversation.